# Is it possible to have different hosting like php/java/python on VPS server

Tags: java, php, web-server, vps

I have the VPS server with Centos with php/apache/cpanel/whm.

I have 20 websites hosting mainly with php.

Now i have got few clients who want to use java/jsp on websites.

I want to know that is it possible to use same VPS/whm to host those websites as well or i need different VPS for java or python/django

Comment: possible but not easy, further more it might not be very stable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [NginX](http://nginx.org/) as a frontend listening on port 80 to forward requests to backend web servers. It's lightweight and consumes very little memory, so its presence would hardly become a problem for you, performance-wise. NginX forwarding requests to Apache listening on port 90 (for example) and Tomcat or some other java web container/app server listening on port 91 sounds like an ideal solution to me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, either using [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) or [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) (redirecting requests to another webserver on another port or machine for the new language) or by running multiple modules (e.g. [mod_python](http://www.modpython.org/)) in the same apache instance.